# IBM cloud private port 8443 not listening after reboot

Tags: docker, ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-private

```
root@pact1:~# kubectl -s http://localhost:8888 get pods --all-namespaces
NAMESPACE     NAME                                                      READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
kube-system   auth-apikeys-9bx2r                                        1/1       Running   3          4d
kube-system   auth-idp-kkt6m                                            3/3       Running   9          4d
kube-system   auth-pap-6brhh                                            1/1       Running   3          4d
kube-system   auth-pdp-6ztzn                                            1/1       Running   3          4d
kube-system   calico-kube-controllers-68786dd655-xrcs4                  1/1       Running   4          5d
kube-system   calico-node-amd64-48t8h                                   2/2       Running   8          5d
kube-system   catalog-catalog-apiserver-hj6pt                           1/1       Running   6          4d
kube-system   catalog-catalog-controller-manager-59d9b88c9d-qgd9z       1/1       Running   8          4d
kube-system   catalog-ui-42vlk                                          1/1       Running   4          4d
kube-system   default-http-backend-6858c684cd-n222g                     1/1       Running   5          4d
kube-system   elasticsearch-client-56cf688d8f-l74tf                     2/2       Running   8          4d
kube-system   elasticsearch-data-0                                      1/1       Running   4          4d
kube-system   elasticsearch-master-86fddbdcb-8bl7p                      1/1       Running   4          4d
kube-system   filebeat-ds-amd64-hbvrw                                   1/1       Running   4          4d
kube-system   heapster-96c84478b-27spb                                  2/2       Running   9          4d
kube-system   helm-api-7767fbc785-kng26                                 2/2       Running   8          4d
kube-system   helmrepo-86c469554-4nlkf                                  1/1       Running   4          4d
kube-system   icp-ds-0                                                  1/1       Running   4          4d
kube-system   icp-management-ingress-lkjlm                              1/1       Running   4          4d
kube-system   image-manager-0                                           2/2       Running   8          4d
kube-system   k8s-etcd-9.199.144.168                                    1/1       Running   4          5d
kube-system   k8s-mariadb-9.199.144.168                                 1/1       Running   5          4d
kube-system   k8s-master-9.199.144.168                                  3/3       Running   12         5d
kube-system   k8s-proxy-9.199.144.168                                   1/1       Running   4          5d
kube-system   kube-dns-amd64-x9vb6                                      3/3       Running   12         4d
kube-system   logstash-5c8c4954d9-bcfkz                                 1/1       Running   4          4d
kube-system   metering-dm-5c4f8bf7c7-jp6xz                              1/1       Running   4          4d
kube-system   metering-reader-amd64-75rv2                               1/1       Running   4          4d
kube-system   metering-server-55c4d77f4c-86l4x                          1/1       Running   4          4d
kube-system   metering-ui-59c65d97d6-mbw45                              1/1       Running   4          4d
kube-system   monitoring-exporter-d8568ffff-sxvtq                       1/1       Running   4          4d
kube-system   monitoring-grafana-78dd9bd7c9-d9hrr                       2/2       Running   8          4d
kube-system   monitoring-prometheus-7994986858-z2lsm                    3/3       Running   12         4d
kube-system   monitoring-prometheus-alertmanager-7dc884c44d-4wbf8       3/3       Running   12         4d
kube-system   monitoring-prometheus-kubestatemetrics-798dd85965-pwxth   1/1       Running   4          4d
kube-system   monitoring-prometheus-nodeexporter-amd64-tzndd            1/1       Running   4          4d
kube-system   nginx-ingress-lb-amd64-546w7                              1/1       Running   7          4d
kube-system   platform-api-gn4gf                                        1/1       Running   4          4d
kube-system   platform-deploy-f6dhv                                     1/1       Running   4          4d
kube-system   platform-ui-cr9n7                                         1/1       Running   4          4d
kube-system   rescheduler-vlfd2                                         1/1       Running   4          4d
kube-system   tiller-deploy-69f658499-6vwpl                             1/1       Running   4          4d
kube-system   unified-router-4qz2r                                      1/1       Running   4          4d
```

Comment: all containers are also running fine still can't open console

Comment: Thanks now the it works

Answer (score 1):

We face this issue related to cluster starting when we reboot ICP . Console throws 500 Internal server Error. Everytime I face this issue I try below solutions. 
1. https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSBS6K_2.1.0.2/getting_started/known_issues.html#alert_500 : Follow this link
2. If the problem does not get resolved, verify 
systemctl status  kubelet docker
3. after doing both the above solutions wait for few mins, clear the browser cache and then opening the console. Many times even if the solution has been fixed due to cache issue , console does not open.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked if there is a firewall rule which is gone since you performed the reboot?
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSBS6K_2.1.0.3/troubleshoot/restart_master_console.html

Comment: i have even disabled firewall still cant connnect to port 8443

Comment: OK then - be sure you used the proper procedures for cluster restart:https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSBS6K_2.1.0.3/manage_cluster/restart_cluster.html

and what version is the ICO?

Comment: i am using icp-ce version 2.1.0.2. Also i will check restart steps again.